# Selenium selector for checkbox pseudo-element

Tags: selenium, css-selectors

```
<label class="casllic_text" for="Checkbox">
::before
<span>Blob <a class="button link" href="abc.pdf">Terms</a> </span></label>
```

I want to click on checkbox.

If I use `label[for="Checkbox"]` as selector, webdriver clicks on Terms link which opens PDF in another tab.

How can I click on checkbox which so far only gets identified if I hover on ::before. (Used inspect element to do that)

Comment: *"...I hover on ::before"*. Are you sure? `::before` is not a DOM element, you cannot handle it

Comment: Open chrome dev tools hover on label and press F8 to pause, then get html with checkbox

Comment: @Andersson sorry let me correct my question. How do I click on the text 'Blob' in above code snippet? Clicking on that marks the checkbox as checked.

Comment: Try XPath `//label[starts-with(., "Blob")]`

Comment: If @Andersson click will open pdf use Action to click with coordinates 1,1

Comment: @Andersson: No, but the ::before is part of the label, so hovering the ::before triggers a hover event on the label itself.